# Remove Router From Express.js Route Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express.js project where I am allowing plugins to be loaded and unloaded at runtime. Plugins have access to the Expess.js router stack to register their paths just like a normal script would such as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(projectCoreObject) {
    function Plugin() { }

    // Plugin initialize called when a plugin is loaded.
    Plugin.Initialize = function (done) {
        // Register the router..
        projectCoreObject.app.use('/', router);
    };

    // GET - /test
    router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
        res.send('Success!');
    });

    return Plugin;
};
```

While this all works great, I have the issue with unloading plugins removing their router from the stack.

Is there a proper way to remove a full router object from Express.js' stack at runtime? I can do individual middleware using their names but with a route like this example shows, the name is just 'router' in the stack.

Comment: I don't believe there is a supported way of doing this.  In the app implementation (which uses a Router internally), there is an array of routes.  You would have to find the right entry in that array and use `.splice()` to remove it from the array.

Comment: You should probably look at socket.io.

Comment: This has nothing to do with socket.io...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using a named function trick to take an anonymous function and turn it into a named one. This way I can remove the router by its name then.